# Update date field based on picklist value

Tags: salesforce-classic, order

Assume when the status is 'hot' on order object. After 30th day the order will be deleted.

Is it possible to create formula field as date. When ischange status is hot the formula field value update TODAY() + 29.

Thanks in advance

Comment: your question is not clear. are you going to update order record or delete the order record after 30 days?

Comment: Actually, I am going to delete order record. Assume today is my order status (pick list)is hot. After 30th day my order will be delete automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think formula field is the solution for this as Formula fields are calculated at run-time which means if you use today()+29, Everytime you open a record the formula field will show the date 30 days later.

What you can rather do is, You can right a process builder which checks for "if status is changed to Hot', If yes, Then It  will update a date field as Today()+29 .

To delete a record, you can right a Flow, this flow you can call from the process builder that you have created.

Hope it answer your query!